# MYsql Query Error Join with Group by not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, grouping

```
Table -1 : Comment id, comment,user_id,comment Date
Table -2: Users id, user_name, full_name, password
```

now i want to get user detaiils records who is last comment

like 
 query is :

```
 select c.*, 
   (select user_name 
    from users 
    where id = c.user_id
   ) as user_name, 
   (select full_name 
    from users 
    where id = c.user_id
   ) as full_name 
from comment as c, users as u 
group by c.user_id 
order by comment_date DESC
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You are using group by without aggregation function   and the use c.* with group by seems that is not clear to the porpuse of group by 
try add a proper data sample and the expected  result 
and also the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT Users.*,
           Comment.*
    FROM Users
    INNER JOIN Comment ON (Comment.user_id = Users.id)
    GROUP BY Users.id
    ORDER BY Comment.id DESC
```

that should work

Comment: this code is perfect but i want to user which is last commented user get first

Comment: this code is working but i want to get user who is last comment

Comment: What results do you get when you run the query above?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query

```
select users.* from users inner join comments on 
users.user_id =  comments.user_id 
order by comments.comment_date desc limit 1
```

Another way to do this

```
select * from users where user_id = 
(select user_id from comments order by comment_date desc limit 1)
```

Comment: in this case get only 1 records but i want to all comment by comment date desc and uniq user_id

Comment: You want all user with last comment?

Comment: yes all last comment user record  by latest comment date